# Invalid report file path. in crystal reports While

Tags: crystal-reports

Am Getting Error Like Invalid Report file While Crystal reports Loading Files ....

OrderWindow objRpt;
            objRpt = new OrderWindow();
            try
            {
                string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString.ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
                OrderDelivery Od = new OrderDelivery();
                Od.Activate();
                DataSet ds = Od.GetProductDetails();
                objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);

```
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
            info.DatabaseName = "BillingAndAccounts";
            info.UserID = "sa";
            info.Password = "sai123";
            SetDBLogonForReport(info, rd);
            rd.Refresh();//Here am Getting Error...

            rd.VerifyDatabase();


            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error show, not getting the path of crystal report file. 
Generally good coding is you set all your crystal report in one folder in your working directory and just create an entry in web.config to access path like

```
<add key="CrystalReportFilePath" value="\Reports"/>
```

And whenever you access or use file, just append the above path with file name (same as connection string in web.config) like

```
var ReportName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrystalReportFilePath"]
```

This code will never give the above error and also code will for maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Crystal Reports runtime continues to look for the report files on the C: drive, even though that drive does not exist, and it reports in the log files that it is looking for the reports on the correct drive letter.

To work around this issue, you will need to map a drive for the C: drive to point to your actual drive.

If you don't know your computer's machine name, right click on the My Computer icon and go to Properties, then to the Computer Name tab. On the Full computer name: line, we need everything up to the . For example, if it says jason.wasp.com, we just need to know "jason". Also for this example, we will use I: as the existing drive.

To map the drive, open your My Computer icon, then on the Tools menu select Map Network Drive. For Drive, select C:. If you don't see C: as an available choice, that letter may have been assigned to a removeable drive in the Disk Management component of Computer Management. Change that drive to another letter; then C: will be available for mapping.